# Is it possible to see what disk blocks a file uses in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, computer-architecture

I would like to see what blocks some files are using. I am talking about files being stored on disk, not blocks in memory. Is this possible in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to get this information using [FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364572(v=vs.85).aspx), see the article on [Defragmenting Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363911(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

Windows does not come with any program that can show this information, so you'll have to either write your own, or try various third-party defragmenters – I have seen one of them having an option to show the on-disk layout for any file; I just cannot remember which.